# Centering off-center content when below certain width (responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a page where my content looks great when shifted slightly to the left via the padding tag (%) in CSS. However, when I decrease the window size down to a more "mobile" size, the content (text) is still slightly to the left. I'd like it to be perfectly centered with a desired amount of padding, after a certain min-width occurs.

Comment: okay. good to know. thanks for sharing. oh and this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and after that `css text-align: center;`?

Answer (score 2):

Use media queries to give the desired effect.

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  div {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
  }
}
```